# Cannot find .cls file

Tags: errors, document-classes

I have a macbook pro and installed MacTeX a few days ago.  Our teacher wants us to do a report using a model of it in cls format. The format is the same folder as the file that I created, however appears to me the error `file ... (file name) not found` and below appears

```
! LaTeX Error: File `... .cls' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
```

How can I solve the problem? I already installed and uninstalled several times Latex and not understand much of it.

The document class is `relatorioFisExpl.cls` and here is my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{relatorioFisExpl} 
\ano{2016} 
\nomedotrabalho[O Pêndulo]{O Pêndulo} 
\dataAulaLaboratorial{14 de março} 
\autorA[48000]{Mary} 
\autorB[48001]{Yasmin} 
\autorC[48002]{Leonard} 
\Turma{PL-23} 
\GrupoNum{3} 
\NomeDocenteLab{George Valentino} 
\dataDoRelatorio{25 de março} 
\begin{document} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you literally type `...` as the name of the class? Because LaTeX seems to think so. What is the line you are using to load the class?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Indeed. I considered that possibility. But in that case, we have *very, very, very almost no* information to go on, as opposed to *very, very almost none*. And the relevant question is still: what line are you using to load the class? And, also, what is the filename of the class?

Comment: In your folder, you should have something like (for example) `myreport.cls`, which your teacher gave you. You need to make a `.tex` file, called (for example) `myfile.tex` (don't call it `myreport.tex` if the class is called `myreport.cls`). This `.tex` file should have at least three lines: `\documentclass{myreport}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.  Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Repeated uninstall/install cycles are not needed, tie consuming and useless. I suggest to [read some very basics](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) to get you started. That will also lead to asking better and understandable questions. By the way, your teacher (who gave you the files) is the best person to help you. He wants you to use a certain piece of software, he should support you.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I put the document tex I created in the same folder as the document template (relatorioFisExpl.cls) of my teacher. I installed MacTex and when I tried to pass my tex to pdf using PDFLaTeX option presented various error rows. The document that I created has these lines:

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti \documentclass[11pt]{relatorioFisExpl}
\ano{2016}
\nomedotrabalho[O Pêndulo]{O Pêndulo}
\dataAulaLaboratorial{14 de março}
\autorA[48000]{Mary}
\autorB[48001]{Yasmin}
\autorC[48002]{Leonard}
\Turma{PL-23}
\GrupoNum{3}
\NomeDocenteLab{George Valentino}
\dataDoRelatorio{25 de março}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Comment: @cfr In the code that I created appears two errors: on line two appears that do not find the cls file and then on line one says: !==> Fatal error ocurred ......... and continues the message but I could not read all.
I've tried to pass a tex document that my teacher made available to pdf and at the start shouldn't give error but gives error.

Comment: @Johannes_B I would very much like to ask my teacher but currently find ourselves on vacation and the next time I can see my teacher, the period of delivery of the work will be close.

Comment: @jon Yes I did it but still says do not find the cls file. I have also tried to pass to pdf one tex document the teacher released but gave error also ...

Comment: Try posting the transcript file as well (the one with the extension `.log`: for instance, if your source file is called `myfile.tex`, you should post `myfile.log`).  Show us the entire contents of this file.

Comment: Please clear the folder of all unnecessary files and then list the names of every file in that folder.  Please also tell us how you are running either `latex` or `pdflatex` (or `lualatex` or `xelatex`).  The `.log` file would also be useful.

Comment: The file that I created, named trabalho do pendulo. The file cls is the only one that is on the list. The file-example of the teacher that gives me error too is exemploRelatorioFisExp2014.tex

Comment: Two things: you have `\documentclass[11pt]{relatorioFisExpl}`, but you need to use `\documentclass[11pt]{relatorioFisExpI}` (capital I, not lowercase l); and you need to use `\nomeDoTrabalho[O Pêndulo]{O Pêndulo}`, not `\nomedotrabalho[O Pêndulo]{O Pêndulo}` (because LaTeX commands are case sensitive by nature).  You might want to make your editor use a font where I and l are clearly distinguishable.

Comment: Also (more generally): don't use spaces in file names and it is good to avoid using periods in file names except for the extension.

Comment: @cfr Now I retired the spaces in the files names, but continues gaves to me error.

Comment: @jon already appear the pdf!! But the accented characters appears to me with the "?" signal, is this normal? I don't believe that! Already can I start the work! :)

Comment: No, that is not normal. It depends on what 'input' format you choose to work with. The `.cls` file seems to want you to use the 'Latin-1' encoding (if you look in the `.cls`, you will see `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}`, which means you cannot input special ãççêñtß (etc.) directly. You must use special commands -- see [this list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) for hints.  Or you can edit the `.cls` file so you can use the UTF-8 encoding, which allows you to type accents normally. (But will your professor want you to do this?)

Comment: To use UTF-8, try changing `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37855/discussion-on-question-by-carmen-gonzalez-cannot-find-cls-file) (some obsolete comments or dropbox links deleted, rest of discussion is still here but may be removed).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz No activity at all, this can probably be closed as unclear? Carmen?

Comment: @Johannes_B That's ok, closed as unclear for now. Still there can be a discussion in chat, and, if meaningful, the question can be clarified and re-opened.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz The room is frozen.